# How can I modify the hosts file on MacOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, dns

I need to test out a site before it's actually live for customers, and doing so with a specific hostname. For this I'd like to modify the [well-known hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)), however it doesnt seem to work.

An answer [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250805304) mentions to do a copy of the file and modify, and then paste it back to the original /etc/hosts location. I've tried it but doesnt work.

I've tried the guide [here](https://www.imore.com/how-edit-your-macs-hosts-file-and-why-you-would-want#how-to-edit-the-hosts-file) too, with restarting the DNS services (`sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`) on my computer. Doesnt work either. I've made a complete reboot too, to no avail.

Have Apple prevented people in MacOS Catalina (10.15.X and later) to modify this file? It seems a lot of people are having problem with this.

Thanks for your help!

**Update**: To clarify: I can successfully change the hosts file and save it, but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Please add the result of `ls -la /etc/hosts`. Then restore the original hosts file, add the line `127.0.0.1 google.xyz` by editing the file with `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and finally enter `ping google.xyz`. Add the result to your question!

Comment: What does *it doesn't seem to work* mean? I copied a `hosts` file from github over that blocks ads/malware and it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it actually did work.

What I did wrong (it seems) is that I had too many spaces between the ip and the hostname inside /etc/hosts. I fixed the spaces with the nano editor and now it works.

It's worth to point out that using `nslookup` will not work however to test your dns change (found reason [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627906/why-is-my-etc-hosts-file-not-queried-when-nslookup-tries-to-resolve-an-address)):

> nslookup only does proper DNS resolution, which is significantly
> different from the Name Service Switch subsystem that your other
> applications use; that is to say nslookup ignores /etc/hosts and mDNS.

Answer (score 3):

What I did was `sudo nano /private/etc/hosts` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

[Gas Mask](https://github.com/2ndalpha/gasmask) is an excellent app to manage your hosts file without using Terminal. I use it to quickly switch between different hosts files for different uses